# Group/Editor permission for language in EPiServer

Tags: content-management-system, globalization, episerver

I have an issue with a large globalized website with alot of languages in EPiServer.

At the moment we have used different nodes for each language, with each spoken language for that country. With this, we have assigned access rights to the node-treew using Editors (e.g NL has EditorsNL). Several of the nodes has Spoken languages as well. For example, the Netherlands has nl-BE and nl-DE.

Example structure:
/NL/asd/BE/ 
/NL/asd/DE/

This causes alot of confusions and misses when the translation begins.

I need **one** tree structure with the languages and set editor access rights depending on what group or editor they are in. Anyone have any tips on what class to use or point me in some direction where to start?

Answer (score 1):

This feature does not exist in current version of EPiServer CMD [5 R2 SP2] but I think it will be a feature of the coming EPiServer CMS 6 release.

To create an intermediate solution, I would check EPiServer.DataFactory class where you have events for SavingPage, etc. You can hook this event and add an extra security check.

This is on a low level so if you want to give better feedback to the editors maybe hooking LoadedPage event on class EPiServer.UI.Edit.EditPanel instead. This event is fired everytime you load the editor for a page. You could add extra security checks here and since you have access to the APS.NET Page for the editor you could find controls and disable them if an editor is not allowed to change stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In EPiServer 6+ you can assign users/groups to languages in admin mode: `Config` ~> `Manage Website Languages`, select a language and edit access rights.

[image: Example of custom access rights for a language in EPiServer]